# Wrong CGImageGetBytesPerRow value for vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888 usage

Tags: ios, cgbitmapcontextcreate

At start I need to do a fast real-time image blur. Found a useful tutorial [Perform a blur using vImage.](http://indieambitions.com/idevblogaday/perform-blur-vimage-accelerate-framework-tutorial/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20IndieAmbitions%20%28Indie%20Ambitions%29)

Here is the code sample

```
-(UIImage *)boxblurImage:(UIImage *)image boxSize:(int)boxSize {
    CGImageRef img = image.CGImage;

    vImage_Buffer inBuffer, outBuffer;

    vImage_Error error;
    void *pixelBuffer;

    //create vImage_Buffer with data from CGImageRef

    CGDataProviderRef inProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(img);
    CFDataRef inBitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(inProvider);

    inBuffer.width = CGImageGetWidth(img);
    inBuffer.height = CGImageGetHeight(img);
    inBuffer.rowBytes = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);

    inBuffer.data = (void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(inBitmapData);

    //create vImage_Buffer for output

    pixelBuffer = malloc(CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img) * CGImageGetHeight(img));

    if(pixelBuffer == NULL)
        NSLog(@"No pixelbuffer");

    outBuffer.data = pixelBuffer;
    outBuffer.width = CGImageGetWidth(img);
    outBuffer.height = CGImageGetHeight(img);
    outBuffer.rowBytes = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);

    //perform convolution
    error = vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, &outBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, boxSize, boxSize, NULL, kvImageEdgeExtend);

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error from convolution %ld", error);
    }

    //create CGImageRef from vImage_Buffer output
    //1 - CGBitmapContextCreateImage -

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(outBuffer.data,
                                         outBuffer.width,
                                         outBuffer.height,
                                         8,
                                         outBuffer.rowBytes,
                                         colorSpace,
                                         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);

    UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    //clean up
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    free(pixelBuffer);
    CFRelease(inBitmapData);

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return returnImage;
}
```

The problem is that function throw an exception on some images. I found only one image ["Broken image"](https://soulmater.s3.amazonaws.com/a906e84ad9f7008880297d12219e00ec.jpg?Signature=K0KrAQuvhrAZBBamRSSakppN%2bCg=&Expires=1875717954&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJU375HQUTFQ7ZZ7Q) (it is JPEG, not PNG).

There is the exception

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 538 bytes/row.
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
```

I started to google it. Found couple of solutions.
After some time spent debugging, i found that `CGImageGetBytesPerRow` return wrong value for "broken image". It fits to original image width, instead of exceed it four times as it should.

I tried to change `rowBytes` in `CGBitmapContextCreate` manually, but there are a lot of artifacts beginning to appear on image. The point is that bug is mysterious, its appear from times to times, but still.

How i can resolve it without of checking the `rowBytes` of the buffers? I can do some precheck of `rowBytes` value and return original image, but it looks like hack. And how happended so that some of the images, like our one, returns wrong `rowBytes` value?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage / vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer?

```
vImage_Buffer buf = {0};
vImage_CGImageFormat fmt = {
    .bitsPerComponent = 8,
    .bitsPerPixel = 32,
    .colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image),
    .bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
};

vImage_Error err = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage( &buf, &fmt, NULL, image, kvImageNoFlags ); // allocates buf.data 

vImage_Buffer outBuffer;
vImageBuffer_Init( &outBuffer, buf.height, buf.width, fmt.bitsPerPixel, kvImageNoFlags);
vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&buf, &outBuffer, ...);
free(buf.data);

CGImageRef newImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer( &outBuffer, &fmt, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoAllocate, &err );  // outBuffer.data will be freed when the CGImageRef is released.
```